# Strings and Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, encryption

I want to create a simple cipher.

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

def main():
  while True:
      plain = raw_input("text to be encoded: ")
      print encode(plain)

def encode(plain):
      length = len(plain)
      plain = plain.upper()
      for c in plain:
          encoded = _______
      return encoded
```

> Input : CAT , Output : MXU

I have this template in mind but What is the best way to do this ? If I have to use dictionary, how do I use it in given set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your two strings:

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
```

Create a dictionary using [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
mydict = {k:v for k, v in zip(alpha, key)} # Or dict(zip(alpha, key))
```

Then in your `encode()` function, you can just do:

```
def encode(plain):
    return ''.join([mydict.get(i, i) for i in plain])
```

`[mydict.get(i, i) for i in plain]` Is equivalent to:

```
newlist = []
for i in plain:
    newlist.append(mydict.get(i, i))
```

[`mydict.get(i, i)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is equivalent to `mydict[i]`, but if there is no key `i`, then `i` (the second parameter) is returned (instead of raising a KeyError)

Note that the list will return something like `['M', 'X', 'U']`, so the [`''.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will print it as `'MXU'`

Answer (score 3):

A very efficient way of doing this is to make use of the [`.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method of strings:

```
import string

alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

cipher = string.maketrans(alpha, key)

def encode(plaintext):
    return plaintext.translate(cipher)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
key = "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"

inp = 'CAT'

_d = {e[0]: e[1] for e in zip(alpha, key)}

print _d


print ''.join([_d[ele] for ele in inp if ele in _d])
```